# Need for Dense layer in Text Classifcation

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, text, text-classification

While creating a model for text classification, what is the need for a Dense Layer? I noticed in multiple examples the following is the structure. A softmax is what required right instead of the Dense Layer?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, 64),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Consider the following sentence in 5 class classification:

"movie is good" . The model structure could be:

```
a = activation_unit
emb= embedding_vector(word)

a0 -> emb("movie") ->a1->emb("is") ->a2->emb("good") ->a3, and

sample_y = softmax(np.dot(Wya,a3))  

and
sample_y = [0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1]
```

which says the sentence belongs to "class 4". **So where is the need for a "Dense Layer"?** Can anyone please explain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In neural networks meant for classification, you need a linear layer before the softmax to project the internal representation, which has some dimensionality $d_i$, to the output space, which has dimensionality $d_o$ equal the number of choices (5 in your case).

So you either place a `Dense(5)` layer after the BiLSTM or you take the output of the BiLSTM "manually" and implement the projection.

The code above has some strange things:

- Uses `numpy.dot` to multiply the output of the BiLSTM. Is this a typo and you actually meant `tf.dot` or `tf.matmul`?
- The model ends with a `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)`, maybe because it was originally meant for binary classification.
- Has both a Dense layer and then a dot product (i.e. matrix multiplication). These two operations are equivalent to a single Dense layer, so it is pointless to have both.

So yo answer your question: assuming that the `np.dot` actually means a tf matrix multiplication, then the Dense layer in the model is pointless.

Comment: Exactly. My bad, i actually meant tf.matmul in which case the Dense is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Softmax is simply an activation function. In your example of 5 class classification, you will need a dense layer with 5 output neurons on which you can then apply softmax to obtain the probability for each class.